# Incompatability between django-import-export and jazzmin

Tags: django-import-export

The django project I'm working on has jazzmin installed and customizing the django admin panel. I was running into an issue where I could import django-import-export along with my model into the python console and could retrieve the data as csv output in the console, but I could not export the data from the admin panel.
Unable to find anything online that addresses the issue.
[Resource not populating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pq7E.png)

django-import-export: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
django-jazzmin: https://django-jazzmin.readthedocs.io

Commented the jazzmin code out and django-import-export works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

We have a section in the [docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.6/advanced_usage.html#interoperability-with-3rd-party-libraries) which covers interoperability.  If you can provide more detail on the nature of the issue, please raise a new [issue](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues).  Although we may not be able to fix it, we will at least have an understanding of the issue.

Comment: Essentially when Jazzmin is configured in the project, when I click on the export button the resource doesn't populate on the export screen. So it doesn't seem like it is transferring over the necessary resource. With the Jazzmin package disabled, import-export works just fine. I'm unable to share any of the code base, but I figured at least this is a documented issue as I couldn't find it anywhere else when I scoured the internet. Added a picture if that's at all helpful.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/farridav/django-jazzmin/issues/459) could be the issue or related?